# Rewriting binary links to use CDN

Tags: tridion, cdn, tridion-2011, templating

CDN integration seems to be a hot topic among Tridion crowd. But, somehow, available discussions mainly revolve around pushing content to/fro CDN. What i'm specifically interested is:

**What will be the proper way of modifying/prefixing inline images outbound links to use CDN?**

The simplest way to go would be to create some post-processing TBB, operating on *Output* item, and place it inside 'Default Finish Actions'. Though, doing this on CD side would seem to be more correct, ain't it so?

**EDIT**

Consider fancier case: what if not only I want to modify image paths, but **wrap the whole image links into ASP.Net controls**. Where do I do this?

**EDIT 2**

So far, implemented  tag to ASP.Net control replacement via TBB. Went smooth, only needed to keep an eye on the following subtle matters:

- Consider CSS inline styles (i.e.: background-image: url(..))
- New TBB needs to be placed **after** any link-manipulating logic (e.g.: Extract Binaries from Html, Publish Bnaries in Package, Link Resolver)
- The quickest and most robust implementation is probably with a simple string replacements (in contrast to regexp's or XML parsing)
- To keep standard "Preview" logic intact, some condition is necessary to trigger the logic

Comment: Right now this question seems mostly focused on starting a discussion. Although it is definitely an interesting topic, Stack Overflow isn't intended (nor the best platform) for such discussions. Is there any way you can share your CDN approach in the question and tell us which doubts you have about it?

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to go with ASP.NET controls for your CDN-hosted images, you may consider these phases/steps:

1. write a TCDL tag (e.g. `<tcdl:image id="..." path="..."`) on CM during rendering
2. write a TCDL `TagHandler` implementation that transforms the TCDL into an ASP.NET include during deployment
3. write the ASCX control to do the CDN lookup proper when the visitor requests the page

I'm not sure if both step 2 and 3 are needed. You might also simply write the CDN path during the deployment phase (step 2 above).

At the same time I'd expect you to upload (updated) images to the CDN using a deployer extension, so that it also happens during phase 2.

Comment: For a simple implementation, you could also just put 'http://my.cdn.com/images' in the Image Url property of the publication. Or is that not supported by Tridion?

Comment: In the above plan (<img/> => <tcdl:../> => <asp:../>) TCDL part seems to be redundant, because: 1. Link resolution occurs on CM-side anyway, 2. TCDL heavy lifting (on both ends) serves no particular purpose, except for trivial text transform, 3. Platform-invariance is not mandated, so injecting <asp:../> on template post-processing works just fine.

Comment: "1. Link resolution occurs on CM-side anyway" PublishBinary/AddBinary indeed calculate the path at publish time. If you use binary links, the TCDL gets transformed into a path at request time and thus will handle things like moves/renames much more easily.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen good point, but AFAICS there's no TCDL tag for images by default ?

Comment: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/linknottcdl_concept_B72F4D64713F4682B61C838A013DF8F8 (log on required) see `tridion:BinaryLink`.